# Quiz creation in unity3D

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have been creating a quiz in unity for a few days, and cant figure out the best way to do it. I have 8 questions, each with 4 answers. I need the answers to add up to determine one or 6 different results. I am using a different scene for each question/result, should I change that?

Should I just spawn in the answers for each question and then when one is clicked remove them and spawn the next set? A tutorial would be great, but I can't find any that suit my needs.

Here are all the [questions, answers, and results](http://prntscr.com/7sz9fw). It would be incredibly helpful if anyone can find the best way soon, the quiz is on a schedule. This will be a mobile app, so please make sure it would work on mobile.

The way I am doing it now is creating a different scene for each question/result and having the answers pre-spawned, but with that I cant figure out how to have that custom result. Thanks a ton! Here is the link to the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/NickGreiner/unityGame).

Comment: Do you have any sample code to show?

Comment: Lots, but its not really a problem with the code its a problem with figuring out how to do the entire thing. I will upload the unity project to github.

Comment: Uploaded. Link in the edited post.

Comment: I think you are getting downvotes because you have not isolated a single, specific question that people can answer. This site works best if you can do that.

Comment: Yeah I got that xD thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. I am going to continue my way, with prebuilt scenes, and use PlayerPrefs to store the quiz data and use that to determine the final result. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html